# Allow dash or hypen javascript regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

How can I add to allow the dash(-) or hypen(-)

I need to allow the input text starting with `-` before the name example `-Alyssa` or anywhere in the input

Examples

`-Alyssa`

`Alyssa-Reyes`

`Alyssa-`

```
const NAME_PATTERN = /^[A-Za-z\u00f1\u00d1\u2019\u0027]+(([' -][A-Za-z\u00f1\u00d1\u2019\u0027 ])?[A-Za-z\u00f1\u00d1\u2019\u0027]*)*[-]?$/;
```

UPDATE. I just added `-` after the \u0027 so it looks like this

```
const NAME_PATTERN = /^[A-Za-z\u00f1\u00d1\u2019\u0027-]+(([' -][A-Za-z\u00f1\u00d1\u2019\u0027 ])?[A-Za-z\u00f1\u00d1\u2019\u0027]*)*[-]?$/;
```

Comment: Just one hyphen or are you going to allow for the occurrence of many instances of a hyphen in which case `[a-zA-Z-]+` would work.

Comment: @Andy it should allow many instances since it should allow hypen in the input text

Answer (score 0):

Try and use a regex like this:

```
const regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$";
```

I hope this helps!
As a quick reference, here you can test out multiple regex patterns: https://regexr.com/

Comment: The problem with this regex is that it is possible to match Alyssa--Reyes or ------Alyssa :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this more easily with a small Javascript function.

This function could split a string like "Alyssa-Reyes", with the split pattern of alphabetic characters, to recover only the hyphens, and filter the returned array by keeping only filled strings.

Then we can return a boolean using a few operators:

- Check if our split worked well, if so we have a filled array, otherwise we would have an empty array.
- Check if all characters are only single hyphen, and therefore not double hyphen.

I didn't know if spaces were allowed like "Alyssa-  Reyes" or "Alyssa  -Reyes", so I made you 2 variants.

**Here's the first variant:**

```js
const valuesTest = [
    "Alyssa",
    "--Alyssa-",
    "-Alyssa--Reyes-",
    "Alyssa-Reyes",
    "-Alyssa",
    "-Alyssa-",
    "Alyssa-",
    "Alyssa--",
    "Alyssa- Reyes",
    "Alyssa -Reyes",
];

const checkHyphen = (value) => {
    const hyphens = value.split(/[a-zA-Z]/g).filter(value => value !== "");
    return hyphens.length > 0 && hyphens.every(hyphen => hyphen === "-");
};

valuesTest.forEach(value => {
    console.log(checkHyphen(value) ? `${value} = Valid` : `${value} = Invalid`);
});
```

**Here's the second variant:**

In this second variant, I simply applied the .trim() method on each matched value and filtered via the .map() method.

```js
const valuesTest = [
    "Alyssa",
    "--Alyssa-",
    "-Alyssa--Reyes-",
    "Alyssa-Reyes",
    "-Alyssa",
    "-Alyssa-",
    "Alyssa-",
    "Alyssa--",
    "Alyssa- Reyes",
    "Alyssa -Reyes",
];

const checkHyphen = (value) => {
    const hyphens = value.split(/[a-zA-Z]/g).filter(value => value !== "").map(value => value.trim());
    return hyphens.length > 0 && hyphens.every(hyphen => hyphen === "-");
};

valuesTest.forEach(value => {
    console.log(checkHyphen(value) ? `${value} --> Valid` : `${value} --> Invalid`);
});
```

Good luck to you Alyssa !

Answer (score 0):

What about this regex:

```
/^(?<=[^-])-?[a-zA-Z-]+(?<=[^-])-?$/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/1shERC/1

- `lookbehind` is used at start and end to dis-allow multiple occurrence of `-`
- but inside of the content, multiple `--` is allowed ( thought this is the requirement too)